# JNI Method Call with multple different arguments

Tags: methods, java-native-interface, call

My question is how is lArgs supposed to be byte formatted? I can't find any examples anywhere where args is a list of different objects.

I tried making lArgs an array of object but it didn't work, I guess because an array of object is not a byte array and two strings.

Please help thanks.

```
szMethod            db "externalCallIn",0
szMethodArgs        db "([BLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V",0


invoke JNI_GetStaticMethodID,dJNIenv,lClass,ADDR szMethod,ADDR szMethodArgs
mov  lMethod,eax

invoke JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod,dJNIenv,lClass,lMethod,lArgs
```

The following does not work...

```
LOCAL lClass:DWORD
LOCAL lMethod:DWORD
LOCAL lByteArray:DWORD
LOCAL lString1:DWORD
LOCAL lString2:DWORD

invoke JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod,dJNIenv,lClass,lMethod,lByteArr,lSt‌​r1,lStr2

JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod PROTO :DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD,:DWORD

JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod PROC inJNIenv:DWORD, inClass:DWORD, inMethod:DWORD, inByteArr:DWORD,‌ ​inStr1:DWORD, inStr2:‌​DWORD
push inStr2
push inStr1
push inByteArr
push inMethod
push inClass
push inJNIenv
mov eax,inJNIenv
mov eax,[eax]
call DWORD PTR [eax].JNIenv.CallStaticVoidMethod
ret
JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod ENDP
```

If I just have 1 argument it works fine. I cannot find any examples that show how to have multiple different arguments. An example will be greatly appreciated many thanks.

This is the java class...

```
public class MyClass
 {
 public static void externalCallIn(byte[] _bytes,String _s1,String _s2)
  {
  ...
  }
 }
```

Comment: `CallStaticVoidMethod` takes a variable number of arguments, so your proto should look something like `JNI_CallStaticVoidMethod PROTO C :DWORD,:VARARG`, and then you need to supply the correct number of arguments when you call it. If you intended to use `CallStaticVoidMethodA` you need to create an array of `jvalue`s and pass its address to `CallStaticVoidMethodA`. That seems like more work than just using `CallStaticVoidMethod` IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are correct but I didnt ask the question very well. Please note the changes Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code I posted.
In the procedure code where I put the byte array together I was not returning the structure pointer in eax. A silly mistake to make.
Once I corrected this everything worked as expected.